# sublimeLinter - jshint warning about "unnecessary escaping" in regex string

Tags: javascript, regex, jshint

```
            return new RegExp('^https\://wtinbox\.worktile\.com/(.*)$');
```

jsHint shows a wrong warning:

Bad or unnecessary escaping for
 "\:" and "."

The escape above is necessary for RegEx. How can I config linter to forgive this?

Thanks!

Comment: *"jsHint shows a wrong warning"* No it doesn't. `'\:'` is the same as `':'`. Same for `'\.'`. Those are not valid escape sequences, hence JavaScript will just resolve them to the character itself. *"The escape above is necessary for RegEx."* But you are not escaping the characters in the regular expression, you are escaping them in the string.

Comment: Felix, that's exactly my mistake is. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to match `.`, then you need to escape `.` with double backslash in the `RegExp` constructor, like this

```
console.log(new RegExp("\.").test("a"));
# true
console.log(new RegExp("\\.").test("."));
# true
console.log(new RegExp("\\.").test("a"));
# false
```

Also, you don't need to escape `:` in the Regular Expressions because it has no special meanings.

It is better to use RegEx literal, like this

```
console.log(/\./.test("a"));
# false
console.log(/\./.test("."));
# true
```